# Syntax error in importing a python package

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I wanted to use the flask-opencv-streamer python package but cannot seem to find a workaround on how to import it.

If i use the example code at here: https://pypi.org/project/flask-opencv-streamer/#description , I will get an import error and in case if I change the '_' to '-',it gives syntax error.

```py
from flask-opencv-streamer.streamer import Streamer
import cv2

port = 3030
require_login = False
streamer = Streamer(port, require_login)

# Open video device 0
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = video_capture.read()

    streamer.update_frame(frame)

    if not streamer.is_streaming:
        streamer.start_streaming()

    cv2.waitKey(30)
```

Comment: Of course you shouldn't change something (to invalid syntax), especially if you have no clue what you're doing. How did you install `flask_opencv_streamer`? Any errors during installation?

Comment: there are no errors and i installed it using pip

Comment: You might have different Python installations on your computer. If that is the case the package could be installed for an other Python version.

Comment: You simply have the wrong syntax, use: `from flask_opencv_streamer.streamer import Streamer`

Comment: if using from flask_opencv_streamer.streamer import streamer, I'll encounter import error and I think its possibly due the fact the package is installed as flask-opencv-streamer

Comment: Here is the exact error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iqram/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_opencv_streamer.streamer import Streamer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_opencv_streamer'

Comment: The package can't be installed as `flask-opencv-streamer`. That would be invalid syntax for an import.

Comment: after installing and uninstalling conda and all the python package,it finally worked somehow. THanks all for helping.